# regex to match what is not matched

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a regex to search through just under 2 million product numbers: `-([A-Za-z0-9]{1-5})$` to match the MFG code (last few letters after the last dash) for example, `G4F,XB-RJG4 SJG2G-TRMH` would match `-TRMH`.  This was supposed to match every string on my list, however, I am a couple thousand short.  This probably means that some were formatted wrong.

what could I do to match a string that doesn't end in -XXXXX, -XXXX, -XXX, or -XX, or in other words, match what is not matched?

Comment: What are you using to search? And what are you searching it in?

Comment: I am using notepad++ which uses the standard PCRE

Comment: Your original regex looks strange, shouldn't it be `-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}$`? Inverse is: `.*(?<!-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5})$`.

Comment: oops! yes it should. Although it still worked fine. Commas shouldn't be there but I have the parenthesis because I am replacing the dash using ,\1 to make ,XXXX

Comment: @Kudla69 You still have problem with repetition quantifier.

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov Your inverse suggestion didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two steps:

1. In the search dialog, tick "Bookmark line"
2. After the search is done, click "Search -> Bookmark -> Inverse Bookmark"

Alternatively, in step 2: "Search -> Bookmark -> Remove bookmarked lines"; afterwards, only the lines that didn't match the regular expression remain.

Comment: @Kudla69 I've added an alternative.

Comment: Yep, I found that just before I deleted my comment :]
Thanks!